# How to create a script that will copy tables from another schema into my schema using PL/SQL advanced scripting in SQLDEV?

Tags: sql

So, I'm trying to create a script that will generate SQL codes for copying tables from HR schema into my own schema.

What I got so far is this but it's incorrect... will anyone help me or give me hints?

```
select 'create table ' || USER_TABLES || '_copy as select *  from ' || USER_TABLES || ';'from hr_tables;
```

Please help me I'm new at this and so desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE ' ||table_name || '_copy AS SELECT *  FROM ' || table_name || ';'
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE OWNER = 'HR';
```